# extract text between 2 paterns and check it one of the patterns contain a char and skip to the next one if match

Tags: regex, sed

i have a file with something like that

```
toto
titi
miam mian
hello
#hello
etc...
```

i try to extract the text between toto and hello
and i use:

```
sed -n '/toto/,/hello/p'
```

It work for 95% of the time, but it happen that the files doesnt have the same syntax and the text have

```
#hello
hello
```

or

```
 #  Hello
Hello
```

or differents variables but still with the commented before the matching pattern
So this is my question: is it possible to says to sed that if he match the pattern Hello, he also have to check if this pattern doesnt contains a special char and a this moment to go to the next matching pattern ?
(it's not possible to put ^Hello because sometimes there is a random number of spaces before)

so the result should be

```
toto
titi
miam mian
 #  hello
 hello
etc...
```

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: would `/^ *hello/` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^ *toto\b/,/^ *hello\b/p' file.txt
```

allows for a file.txt like this:

```
ppp
 totox
   toto
titi
miam mian
 # hello
XhelloW
   hello
ppp
```

and prints

```
   toto
titi
miam mian
 # hello
XhelloW
   hello
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution, i made a:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v "#" | sed -n '/toto/,/hello/p'
```

looks to be good like that :)

Comment: is `#` the only special char you’re expecting ? What if there is a `chellox` entry before the `hello` ?

Comment: In plain sed, that's `sed -n -e '/#/n;/toto/,/hello/p'` ... but your answer doesn't appear to produce the output you request in your "the result should be" block... you omit the comments.  The sed `n` is the skip-to-next that you want.